# Will dataLayer.push() definitely send data to google when triggered on an anchor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, google-tag-manager

This may seem like a simple question, but it doesn't seem to be answered anywhere that i can find.

I am writing an `onClick` event handler that simply calls `dataLayer.push()` when an anchor is clicked.

Is `dataLayer.push()` a synchronous operation?

Will the GET request to google definitely be sent, even though the browser has unloaded the page it was requested from due to the link being followed?

Some browsers show the connection get cancelled, some show it success.

My question is if the computer is slow, is it possible for the page to get unloaded before the request is sent?

This is why i assume that google started using the `eventCallback` property to redirect the user after the link has been followed.
e.g.
https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#product-clicks

This source code does not include the click handler, but implies that the `onClick` event should stop propogation and let the `eventCallback` function set `document.location`.

However, as soon as you cancel the event, all its information has gone.

This (in my opinion) is just the wrong way to do it.
e.g.
(CTRL or COMMAND) + Click opens a new tab on browsers. This will not work unless the `onClick` event handler allows the prorogation to continue.

Relying on `eventCallback` also means that if the google scrips didn't load for one of the many reasons it could (but is still unlikely), your links don't work. And your site is broken.

So this leaves the correct way to do it for the `onClick` event handler to allow the event to propagate and return true.

Which also means that `dataLayer.push()` would need return after the GET request was sent for any of this to work properly.

Code example:
NOTE: You will get mixed results in mixed environments.

```
<a href="/somewhere-else">Link</a>


$(document).on('click', 'a', function(event) {

    // Is dataLayer.push() guaranteed to fire a GET ?
    // data set externally
    dataLayer.push(data);

    return true;
```

});

Is there anyone out there that can guarantee that the GET request will get fired to the google server?

Have the google developers forgotten something here?

EDIT: Updated title to be more relevant to the question.

Comment: While I think this is a good question for a discussion (and have offered an answer) SO is generally not a discussion forum, so to ask if a vendor's solution is a good one will probably be closed as off-topic. You might want to rephrase this as "how can I make sure my data is sent".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

datalayer.push does not send anything to Google. It pushes objects with key/value pairs to the datalayer array. This might contain an event which in turn  fires a tag. Whether the tag is sent depends on the setup of the tag, not on the dataLayer.push.

As a consequence, when you write your own click handlers your are yourself responsible to make sure your tags are actually fired.

If you use the built-in click handler you can [configure a delay to make sure your tag has time to fire before the link redirects](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106961?hl=en#Click):

> Since link clicks usually cause the browser to load a new page and
>   interrupt any pending HTTP request, you have the option to add a small
>   delay to allow tags fired by Tag Manager to execute properly before
>   redirecting to the next page. Checking the “Wait For Tags” option will
>   delay opening of links until all tags have fired or the specified
>   timeout has elapsed, whichever comes first.

You should be able to mix both methods (push data on the click, but still use the "native" link click handler for the event).

[You can also try to specify "beacon" as the transport method](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/sending-hits#specifying_different_transport_mechanisms) in your Google Analytics tags, on browsers that support this (which I think is only Chrome at the moment) GA will then use the navigator.sendBeacon interface, which sends the data even in case the page unloads.

You might think that Google's solution is not very elegant (but the simple delay  has the advantage that it works for all tags, not just for GA), but they have not "forgotten" the problem.

Also solutions that combine GA hit callbacks with timeouts that redirects if the callback fails as proposed i.e. by Simo Ahava somewhere should be be doable with GTM, even if they are probably more cumbersome to implement in GA.

Comment: Thanks for that.. I Was hoping there was a more elegant synchronous solution other than timers to some what work around the issue.

Comment: But i don't think one exists due to browser differences. But this definitely does answer the question. I had been googling for quite a while to find something in google documentation that suggested the behaviour of this event. I was also trying to simplify the question by ignoring the push method / event.

Comment: Just FYI, you can check which browsers support navigator.sendBeacon here: http://caniuse.com/#search=navigator.sendbeacon

Comment: i've been trying to find everywhere how to send an event with `transport` `beacon` with `dataLayer.push` but all i can find is `ga`

Comment: was looking for alternate solution too for something more elegant than setTimeout... but what is the recommended time ? with Firefox, 100ms were not enough. I put 500ms. With chrome, even 0 works...